# How to make search autocomplete faster?

Tags: php, jquery, caching, autocomplete, memcached

I have implemented a basic auto-complete feature using jQuery autocomplete. I am querying DB every time which is making auto-complete thing quite slow. I am looking for ways to make it faster much like Quora.

Here is the code from front-end:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var URL2 = '<?php e(SITE_URL); ?>fronts/searchKeywords';

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var CityKeyword = jQuery('#CityKeyword');

CityKeyword.autocomplete({
minLength    : 1,
source        : URL2
});

});
 </script>
```

Here is the code from server side:

```
function searchKeywords(){

    if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax() ) {
        $this->loadModel('Expertise_area');
        Configure::write ( 'debug',0);
        $this->autoRender=false;

        $expertise=$this->Expertise_area->find('all',array(
                'conditions'=>array('Expertise_area.autocomplete_text LIKE'=>'%'.$_GET['term'].'%'), 
                'fields' => array('DISTINCT (Expertise_area.autocomplete_text) AS autocomplete_text'),
                'limit'=>5
        ));
        $i=0;
        if(!empty($expertise)){
            $len = strlen($_GET['term']);
            foreach($expertise as $valueproductname){
                $pos = stripos($valueproductname['Expertise_area']['autocomplete_text'],$_GET['term']);
                $keyvalue = "";

                if($pos == 0) {
                    $keyvalue= "<strong>".substr($valueproductname['Expertise_area']['autocomplete_text'],$pos,$len)."</strong>"
                            .substr($valueproductname['Expertise_area']['autocomplete_text'],$len);
                }else {
                    $keyvalue= substr($valueproductname['Expertise_area']['autocomplete_text'],0,$pos)."<strong>"
                            .substr($valueproductname['Expertise_area']['autocomplete_text'],$pos,$len)."</strong>"
                            .substr($valueproductname['Expertise_area']['autocomplete_text'],$pos+$len);
                }


                $response[$i]['value']=$valueproductname['Expertise_area']['autocomplete_text'];
                $response[$i]['label']="<span class=\"username\">".$keyvalue."</span>";
                $i++;

            }
            echo json_encode($response);
        }else{
        }
}
}
```

I have researched a bit and so far following solutions are worth looking at:

1. Query data on page load and store it in COOKIE to be used in future.
2. Implement some caching mechanism (memcache??). But my website is on Cakephp which does it internal cahcing if I am right. So will it be worth to go in this direction.
3. Use some third party indexing mechanism like Solr, Lucene etc. Don't know much about this.
4. Implement a much complex "Prefix Search" myself

What is the right way to go about it? Please help me out here.

Comment: Load all the possible results into a variable at DOM load time. Don't use ajax.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I am thinking of doing that .. but would not it be wise to store these keywords somewhere instead of loading everytime?? And if yes, what is the best way to do that? Cookie or session?

Comment: CakePHP is known to be quite slow. It can do the job, but if you want it to be really fast then you have to forget about frameworks and write it by hand. It is not very difficult: Create a PHP file, open a db connection, search for keyword and output it. Done. Using an in-memory data store (like memcache) may speed it up some, though if your database is set up correctly it should be able to handle it (e.g. MySQL is very fast if you use indexes and avoid wild card searches).

Comment: @verri M. Olsen  what is an alternative to wild card search if I have to show any match in strings not just starting chars? How to generate index for them? for example if user enters 'dev' then I have to show "development", "web development", "social development" etc. It is making my query slow.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this but will be doing it soon for a project I'm working on.

I always considered the possibility of during the initial page load recieveing some AJAX (or perhaps just including it in the page) the top 10 words for each alphabet letter.. e.g.

A - apples, anoraks, alaska, angela, aha, air, arrgh, any, alpha, america
B - butter, bob etc.....

This way when user presses A-Z you can instantly provide them with 10 of the most popular keywords without any further requests, as you already have them stored in an array in the JS.

I'm not sure of size/memory usage but this could be extended further to handle the first 2 letters, e.g. AA, AB, AC.....BA, BB, BC.... ZA, ZB, ZZ... of course many combinations such as words starting with ZZ won't have any data unless it's a music site and it's ZZ Top!  This means it probably won't take up so much memory or bandwidth to send this data during initial page load.  Only when the user types the 3rd letter do you need to do any further data lookups/transfers.

You auto-update this data every day, week or whatever depending on site usage and the most popular searches.

Comment: problem is that I have to show all results which contain user entry . for example if user enters 'dev' then I have to show "development", "web development", "social development" etc. It is making my query slow.

Comment: well couldn't you do something similar to my idea with this? The value is in the precompution of the results before the user searches for them.

There's no reason why you cannot have 'dev' = ['web development', 'social development'] within the initial page as an array that is searched.

Only you know your data, obviously it would be silly to send 1MB of Javascript, but if you handle 95% of the cases with ease, the other 5% will have a longer wait, but overall will be much quicker as database will be less used thanks to 95% handled without it.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding a solution to my question which I figured out after a lot of research.

Problem was:

1. I was using Ajax to fetch keywords from database every time a user changes text in search box
2. I was doing a wild card search to match search item within entire strings and not just starting of keywords for ex. "dev" would return "social development", "development" etc

Solution:

1. I have a fixed array of keywords (200) which is not going to increase exponentially in near future. So, instead of doing complex indexing I am currently sending all keywords in an array.
2. I am sending this data in an array on page load since it is small. If it becomes large, I will fetch it in background via some ajax in different indexed arrays.
3. I am using jQuery's Autocomplete widget to do rest of thing for me.
4. For highlighting search item, I am using a hack by working around __renderItem. (Copied from Stackoverflow. Thanks to that!!)

Code:

```
function monkeyPatchAutocomplete() { //Hack to color search item

jQuery.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function( ul, item) {
    var re = new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + this.term + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi");
    var t = item.label.replace(re,"<span style='font-weight:bold;color:#434343;'>" + 
            "$&" + 
            "</span>");
    return jQuery( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + t + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
}

function getKeywords(){ 
//Function that returns list of keywords. I am using an array since my data is small.
//This function can be modified to fetch data in whatever way one want. 
//I intend to use indexed arrays in future if my data becomes large.

    var allKeywords = <?php echo json_encode($allKeywords); ?>;

    return allKeywords;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

monkeyPatchAutocomplete();

var CityKeyword = jQuery('#CityKeyword');

CityKeyword.autocomplete({
minLength    : 1,
source        : getKeywords()
});

});
```